# How to deal with a ref within a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my parent component with multiple inputs from a loop. How can I choose one `input` to focus? Do I have to create a dynamic `ref` in this case?

```
class TestRef extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        name: "abc"
      },
      { name: "def" }
    ]
  };
  focusInput = () => this.ref.current.focus();
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(o => {
          return <Hello placeholder={o.name} ref={this.ref} />;
        })}
        <button onClick={this.focusInput}>focus input 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.focusInput}>focus input 2</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to references, these can not be dynamic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In react how to get ref of first element that's rendered from Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820031/in-react-how-to-get-ref-of-first-element-thats-rendered-from-map)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) to generate and store the dynamic ref of each input in an array. Now you can refer to them using the index of the ref:

```js
const Hello = React.forwardRef((props,  ref) => <input ref={ref} />);

class Button extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => this.props.onClick(this.props.id);

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.children}</button>
    );
  }
}

class TestRef extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        name: "abc"
      },
      { name: "def" }
    ]
  };
  
  inputRefs = [];
  
  setRef = (ref) => {
    this.inputRefs.push(ref);
  };
  
  focusInput = (id) => this.inputRefs[id].focus();
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(({ name }) => (
          <Hello 
            placeholder={name} 
            ref={this.setRef} 
            key={name} />
        ))}
        <Button onClick={this.focusInput} id={0}>focus input 1</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.focusInput} id={1}>focus input 2</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestRef />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If the list wouldn't be static, and items may be removed/replaced, you should probably use a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) to hold the refs, or any other method of adding the ref by a constant `id`. You should also check before using the ref, because it might not exist:

```js
const Hello = React.forwardRef((props,  ref) => <input ref={ref} />);

class Button extends React.Component {
  onClick = () => this.props.onClick(this.props.id);

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.children}</button>
    );
  }
}

class TestRef extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [{ name: "abc" }, { name: "def" }, { name: "ghi" }]
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(({ data }) => ({
        data: data.slice(0, -1)
      }))
    }, 3000);
  }
  
  inputRefs = new WeakMap;
  
  setRef = (id) => (ref) => {
    this.inputRefs.set(id, ref);
  };
  
  focusInput = (id) => {
    const input = this.inputRefs.get(id);
    
    if(input) input.focus(); // use only if the ref exists - use optional chaining ?. if possible instead
  }
  
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(o => (
          <Hello 
            placeholder={o.name} 
            ref={this.setRef(o)} 
            key={o.name} />
        ))}
        
        <br />
        
        {data.map((o, i) => (
          <Button onClick={this.focusInput} id={o} key={o.name}>focus input {i + 1}</Button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestRef />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: very useful solution

Comment: does this not work with a functional componenet... i see you have a function generating the refereces as they are loaded in. i see the ref argument but i do not see it passed in as a parameter? Is this a special key word or am i missing something?

Comment: I am just wondering where (ref) is coming from as nothing is passed in...

Comment: The `this.setRef` function is passed to the `<Hello>` component as ref. The `<Hello>` component passes the ref to the `<input>`, which calls the function and passes the `ref` to it via `(ref)`. Read about [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

Comment: What happens if the first Hello component gets removed? Are the refs still consistent? e.g. refs[0] still points to the old Hello that gets removed isn't it?

Comment: I've added a 2nd part to the answer, that deals with changes such as changing/removing elements.

Answer (score 18):

if you are coming to this question 2020 here is how you create multiple refs using create hooks in a loop

```
   const MyComponent=(){
    // empty list to put our refs in
    let LiRefs = []
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <ul className="event-list">
            // Check if my data exists first otherwise load spinner 
            {newData ? (
              newData.map((D) => {
                // the cool part inside the loop 
                // create new ref 
                // push it into array 

                const newRef = createRef();
                LiRefs.push(newRef);
                return (
                  // link it to your li 
                  // now you have list of refs that points to your list items 
                  <li key={D._id} ref={newRef}>
                    title : {D.title} <br />
                    description : {D.description}
                    <br />
                    data : {D.date} <br />
                    price : {D.price}
                    <br />
                    <div>creator : {D.creator.username}</div>
                    {authData.token && (
                      <button type="button" id={D._id} onClick={handelBooking}>
                        Book
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </li>
                );
              })
            ) : (
              <Spinner />
            )}
          </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
 }
```

Comment: I don't see the cool part of having a .map to have a side effect like that...

Comment: Although with some refactoring the pattern works and is readable, so I remove the down vote for the idea.

Comment: I would expect the 2020 answer to be using hooks rather than `createRef`. There are caveats in this approach especially when the list is dynamic. `useRef` should be used rather than `createRef` or even better callback ref.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of adding refs to an array using hooks is by creating a `useRef([])` then filling the array with your refs, then assigning the refs to the element. Like so:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'

const myComponent = ({items}) => {

    const refArr = useRef([])
    refArr.current = items.map((item, index) => {
        return refArr.current[index] || React.createRef();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <button ref={refArr.current[index]}>click me</button>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a general useFocus hook

```
// General Focus Hook
const useFocus = (initialFocus = false, id = "") => {
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState(initialFocus)
    return ([
        (newVal=true) => setFocus(newVal), {
            autoFocus: focus,
            key: `${id}${focus}`,
            onFocus: () => setFocus(true),
            onBlur: () => setFocus(false),
        },
    ])
}

const data: [{
        name: "abc"
    },{ 
        name: "def" 
}]

const TestRef = () => {

    const focusHelper = data.map( (_,i) => {
        const [setFocus, focusProps]= useFocus(false, i)
        return {setFocus, focusProps}
    }) 

    return (
      <div>
        {data.map( (o,i) => (
          <Hello placeholder={o.name} {...focusHelper[i].focusProps} />;
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => focusHelper[0].setFocus()}>focus input 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => focusHelper[1].setFocus()}>focus input 2</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

You can find more info here: [Set focus on input after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/set-focus-on-input-after-render/54159564#54159564)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it for React Functional Programming and Typescript!

First create the ref array

```
   const refsById = useMemo(() => {
    const refs: any = {};
    items.forEach((item: ItemType, index: number) => {
        refs[index] = React.createRef(); 
    })
    return refs;
}, [items])
```

Then add the ref in your template

```
return (
    <div>
        {items.map((item: ItemType, index: number) => {
            return <input key={item.id} ref={refsById[index]} />
        })}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I discovered another way of tackling this:

```
let dataCount = 0;

class TestRef extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        name: "abc"
      },
      { name: "def" }
    ]
  };
  focusInput = (thisHello) => this[`ref${thisHello}`].current.focus();
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(o => {
          dataCount++
          return <Hello placeholder={o.name} ref={(el) => { this[`ref${dataCount}`] = el; }} />;
        })}
        <button onClick={() => this.focusInput(1)}>focus input 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.focusInput(2)}>focus input 2</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `dataCount` is unnecessary if your Hello element has a key or unique ID to use as a variable.