# Same Function is Triggered IN Multiple Components

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using `react-native-material-menu`'s popup for showing menu options.

But the issue is, it's not working for multiple scenarios.

I mean when I click on first menu button, the same methods gets triggered and hence the same menu is opened every time.

What should be the better approach for to handle this particular scenario.

Here is the [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@zain143/multiple-component-with-same-function)

```
_menu = null;

 setMenuRef = ref => {
     this._menu = ref;
 };

 hideMenu = () => {
     this._menu.hide();
 };

 showMenu = () => {
     this._menu.show();
 };


{this.state.clientsList.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.caseItem} >
                            <Card style={styles.card}>
                                <CardItem>
                                    <Body>
                                        <View style={styles.rowTitle}>
                                            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.FullName}</Text>
                                            <Menu
                                                ref={this.setMenuRef}
                                                button={<Icon type="Feather" name="more-vertical" onPress={this.showMenu} style={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#555' }} />}
                                            >
                                                <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>View</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Edit</MenuItem>
                                                <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Delete </MenuItem>
                                            </Menu>
                                        </View>

                                        <View>
                                            <Text style={styles.lbl}>Email: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>{item.EmailID}</Text></Text>
                                            <Text style={styles.lbl}>Client Type: <Text style={styles.lblValue}>{item.ClientType}</Text></Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </Body>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
                        </View>
                    );
                })}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using same reference for all menu components

you have to use different ref for every Menu.

1. **Best Approach**:

first way to Create [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for Menu and handle them in it.

2. **Moderate**

or Create Dynamic [Ref in React](https://medium.com/@jalexmayer/react-refs-with-dynamic-names-d2262ab0a0b0) for Menu's List

3. **for running code only**

3rd is to create ref for every menu

```
_menu1 = null;
_menu2 = null; 
_menu3 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the same `ref` every-time. I've not used the library you mentioned but if it has to rely on ref you can create a list of reference instead, syntax is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448143/dealing-with-ref-within-a-loop-in-react).